# When the input matrix is supposed to be: "The rows of X correspond to observations, and columns correspond to variables."?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, sift

I'm not getting the correct results from the Matlab function so maybe my data arrangement is wrong. I looked at the help file of the function I am using and the input, "X" that it takes must be in the form.

> The rows of X correspond to observations, and columns correspond to
>   variables.

I am sorry if this is very basic but how exactly should my input matrix be arranged?

I have 5 writers, each have a feature vector of length 18 (for example for the sake of simplicity).

So I assumed that by `observations` it is meant the different features of the same writer and `variables` mean the writers, so I arranged the input matrix as `[18 x 5]` where each column is a writer.

This example is simple. What of in the case of SIFT features? where each writer will produce a feature matrix `[128 x num. of keypoints]` which usually becomes `[128 x 70]` for one image. So if I want to concatenate all of them into the input matrix my input matrix will become `[128 x 350]`.

Will this just be the input matrix X? Then in the case of SIFT each variable in 70 columns wide.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If all of your writers data have different size, I suggest you to use `cell()` which is cell array. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html - here is your reference. So for example if you need to calculate covariance you can do it for each matrix separately. Then your covariance matrices will be same size(128*128) so you can put them together and have your 3D matrix data. 
Hope it will help you.